# Postfix for internal and external use

Tags: postfix

I have a small Postfix Server (v > 3.0) running which is connected to the Internet. Sending and receiving mails through this interface is fine.

Now on this server I have a second network interface (openvpn) to a different private network with an separate mail server, but there is no DNS server for this network.

I tried a couple of configurations but I couldn't make Postfix send mails for a special Domain through this 2nd Interface. Can somebody give me a hint on how to do that?! I found a lot of information on running multiple domains on one server, but nothing that fits my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transport](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) map/table to route messages for given email domain to IP specific IP address.

```
example.com      smtp:[10.0.0.2]:25
```